# 12345678 = 123 45 67 8 in bash

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, number-formatting

I have a script that takes in one big 17 digit number as input from the command line. I want to separate it into 5 different numbers, each with different no. of digits. Like so:

```
Input: 23063080434560228  
Output of the program:  
Number1: 23063  
Number2: 08  
Number3: 04  
Number4: 3456  
Number5: 0228
```

Now the output of the program (in terms of digits per number) is fixed, i.e, `Number2` will always have 2 digits and so on. Given this sort of a scheme of the output, I am not sure if division is even an option. Is there some `bash` command/utility that I can use? I have looked it over the net and not come across much.

Thanks,
Sriram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Substring Extraction](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
${string:position:length}
```

Extracts `length` characters of substring from `string` starting at `position`.

For example:

```
INPUT=23063080434560228
num1=${INPUT:0:5}
num2=${INPUT:5:2}
num3=${INPUT:7:2}
num4=${INPUT:9:4}
num5=${INPUT:13:4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this directly into an array in one shot in Bash 3.2 or greater.

```
string=23063080434560228
pattern='(.{5})(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})(.{4})'

[[ $string =~ $pattern ]] && substrings=(${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1})

for substring in "${substrings[@]}"; do echo "$substring"; done
```

Comment: that was SUPER AWESOME! pretty fancy!!